# lsof does not detect reading images and video files for thumbnails

Tags: nautilus, lsof

Does `lsof` command detect the reading of images and video files for setting thumbnails for them in nautilus?

I want lsof command to show a file that is read by nautilus for set the thumbnail for that file be it video file or image file.

I use `sudo lsof | grep -E "path_to_new_videofiles"`. And command completes, but shows nothing but thumbnails for videofiles in path_to_new_videofiles are still appointing.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. `lsof` shows only currently opened files. Can you be a bit more specific what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank You, @SimonSudler, you are kind human, nobody congratulated me on stackexchange, security.stackexchange, launchpad, askubuntu and other sites, only you. I want lsof command to show a file that is read by nautilus for set the thumbnail for that file be it video file or image file. Nautilus for appointing thumbnail first opens then read that file, right. Otherwise without open for example video.mp4 file it will not can appoint a thumbnail.

Comment: I can not see video.mp4 video1.mp4 and so one be detected by lsof when first open a folder, where videofiles are copied to and one after another are appearing thumbnails.

Comment: You should add all the comments to your question.

Comment: @Dmytro as Simon suggested, please [edit] your question to provide any additional information. Comments might get lost.

Comment: @guntbert, Simon has cleared my question in his answer. See below.

Comment: @Dmytro Your question should be useful - please take the time to give as much information as possible. It does not matter (as much) if you got a good answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### lsof

`lsof` shows only the currently used resources. By using `sudo lsof | grep -E "filename"` you only get a under sampled result. Executing the `lsof` in exact the right time to catch the `fopen` from nautilus is coincidental at best.

### inotifywait and inotifywatch

To watch IO use [inotifywait](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/inotifywait.1.html) or [inotifywatch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/inotifywatch.1.html). Select the events and file or folder you are interested in.

```
$ inotifywait --recursive --monitor /tmp/test
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/tmp/test/ CREATE new.file
/tmp/test/ OPEN new.file
/tmp/test/ ATTRIB new.file
/tmp/test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE new.file
```